# why i'm getting No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/employee;create=true error in my code?

Tags: java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


package database_console;

/**
 *
 * @author nareshreddy
 */

//import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class DBConnect {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try{


        String host  =  "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/employee;create=true";
        String uName = "root";
        String uPass =  "14mcmi34";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName,uPass );

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement( );

        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM WORKERS";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( SQL );

        while( rs.next( ) ) {
            int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
            String first_name = rs.getString("First_Name");
            String last_name = rs.getString("Last_Name");
            String job = rs.getString("Job_Title");

            String p = "id_col + \" \" + first_name + \" \" + last_name + \" \" + job";

            System.out.println(p);
        }
        }
        catch ( SQLException err ) {
            System.out.println( err.getMessage( ) );
        }


    }

}
```

i'm getting 
"No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/employee;create=true "
error why?
after adding my  "  /home/nareshreddy/HARDDISK/2nd Sem/SE lab/java program/java Jar file/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar "  file also

Answer (score 2):

Your connection string requires a derby DB driver, not a mysql connector.
So download the [Driver](http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.11.1.1.cgi) for Derby DB and  add it to your classpath or if you would like to work with mysql, you have to change the connectionstring to `jdbc:mysql://...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Java.sql.*` or `javax.sql.*` package but your project should import `JDBC` derby jar file.
Because java jdbc packages are the specification of derby `jdbc`

[Here is the Official link you can use](http://db.apache.org/derby/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with mysql then download the driver file and load it using the

> class.forName("driver package.driver class name");

e.g.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

and make sure the connector file is in classpath.

alternatively for the derby change the driver name and make sure the driver jar file is placed at classpath.